# Bootstrap can't see collapsed menu cause of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I don't have a problem with the actual menu opening, I just have an issue whereas the data in the menu can't be seen since there's content over it, obstructing the view - I would've thought the collapsed drop-down menu would be put over the existing content.

This is my current setup which will be summed up with a **jsfiddle** after:

```
<div id="header" style="height: 200px; background-image: url({{ header_image }})" class="background-image">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-partition" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!/home">{{ site_logo_name }}</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse-partition">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!--bootstrap standard link and dropdown-->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrhLbkzf/) - I'm not too sure why there are issues with the dropdown working and when resizing the collapse automatically falls, but that's my code.

*This is a gif of the issue on my server* [gyazo gif](https://gyazo.com/47bb210b9c9760a319bc9d44943c9026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You more than likely have positioned the elements underneath the navbar and since your navbar is wrapped in another element this could be causing issues but it is hard to tell without looking at your full code.  This can be fixed by either adding the class of `navbar-static-top` to your navbar or adding a position to your `#header` and giving this a higher z-index than the elements below your header like so:

```
#header{
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
```

if a z-index of 1 is not high enough try a higher number until it works.

Here is a working fiddle [Working Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/k1mn4hyx/)

P.S.  Your fiddle is not working properly because you forgot to load jquery before bootstrap's js

Comment: **Your fiddle is not working properly because you forgot to load jquery before bootstrap's js** Appologies, and this worked perfectly, thank you sir. :-)